# JS backbone Loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I have an application running, which displays 'loading wheel' while fetching data from server.

All works correctly in Firefox and not in Chrome.

In chrome I can see the loading wheel only after applying `breakpoint`.

Request takes 3-4 seconds to complete. Without breakpoint I can not see the loading wheel.

I have these two wrappers for jquery

```
hideLoadingImage = function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
  };

  showLoadingImage = function() {
    $("#loading").show();
  };
```

So I call it like -

```
myfunc: function(event){
showLoadingImage();
         TASK TO PERFORM --->
         new_model = new FormModel();
         new_model.url = model_url;
         new_model.fetch({ async: false });
         <---------
hideLoadingImage();
}
```

This works correctly in firefox and in chrome debug mode only.
I want to get this work in chrome.

Comment: What is in `task to perform`? Is it running an async call to your server? If it is, then hide is called right after show so the wheel disappears quickly.

Comment: yes it is making `async:false` call. Question updated. Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Backbone Model.fetch delegates to jQuery.ajax. The use of `async:false` is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and greater: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> [..] As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred)
>   is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback
>   options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such
>   as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

You should revamp your script to do the call asynchronously and move `hideLoadingImage` into the callback.

```
new_model.fetch({
success: function(){
        hideLoadingImage();
    }
});
```

This way it will wait until it receives the response to call hide instead of hiding while the request is still in progress.

Comment: Tried this but again it is working with firefox. What I am observing is showLoadingImage() is getting executed but style is not getting reflected immediately, because when I do not call  hideLoadingImage then it is showing the loading wheel after fetching.

Comment: Strange. What HTML is in the loading div? Maybe the gif you're displaying is just taking a long time to render...

Comment: Your answer was helpful, thanks, as codebase is huge I am not going with re-factoring. I will use setTimeout, but in future writing I will make sure to use callbacks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I got this point.

Please let me know if misunderstood.

Chrome was changing element style but network request was blocking the "reflow" whereas mozilla UI thread does not interfere with network hence it worked in mozilla.

Solutions I could find -

1. use setTimeout after successful DOM change.
2. do not use async:false, one should use success,failure callbacks for the same.[suggested above by @Rondel, thanks. ]